# Is there a way to use sed or grep to remove all unnecessary text and show only one word?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to remove all words that are before code=" and after "> in my file so I'm left with clearsky_night or cloudy, or sun etc?

I have tried grep -o -P '(?<=>).*(?=>)' but get an error message sating unknown option to 's'

I also tried grep -o -P '(?<=code=").*(?=" )' but that didn't work either.
This is what's in my file:

```
    <symbol id="Sun" number="1" code="clearsky_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Sun" number="1" code="clearsky_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Sun" number="1" code="clearsky_night"></symbol>
   <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="LightCloud" number="2" code="fair_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Sun" number="1" code="clearsky_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="LightCloud" number="2" code="fair_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="LightCloud" number="2" code="fair_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="LightCloud" number="2" code="fair_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="LightCloud" number="2" code="fair_night"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
```

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: quick and dirty: `grep -oP '(?<=code=").*?(?=")'`

Comment: Another quick-and-dirty method: `grep -Po 'code="\K[^"]*'`

Comment: @Cyrus I will check out xmlstarlet thanks!

Comment: Yet another one: `sed -n 's/.*code="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file`

Comment: Please post vaild XML with only one root node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
grep -o -P '(?<=code=").+?(?=")' input_file.xml
```

I checked with the **[lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** for the usage of `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`.

Or, use `perl` my friend:

```
$ perl -pe 's:^.+code="(.+?)".+$:\1:' <input_file.xml
```

Explanation:

- `perl -pe`: run `perl` with commands including in next string param.
- `s:...:...:`: substitution.
- `"(.+?)"`: things inside `""`, non-gready (`?`).
- `^.+code="`: everything starting from line beginning to `code="`.
- `".+$`: everything from `"` to end of line.

Of course, it is a quick+dirty solution. A XML parser would be better.

(sorry for my broken English)

Comment: Thanks, both work! Also thanks for the explanation, that helps a lot. Your English is great :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have valid XML per @cyrus comment above, you could use an XSLT transform via `xsltproc`:

src.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="symbol">
    <xsl:for-each select="@code">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Use `xsltproc` to transform your xml:

```
xsltproc src.xslt src.xml
```

Output:

```
clearsky_night
clearsky_night
clearsky_night
cloudy
partlycloudy_night
cloudy
partlycloudy_night
partlycloudy_night
partlycloudy_night
partlycloudy_night
cloudy
partlycloudy_night
cloudy
partlycloudy_night
cloudy
cloudy
partlycloudy_night
cloudy
partlycloudy_night
cloudy
cloudy
cloudy
partlycloudy_night
partlycloudy_night
fair_night
partlycloudy_night
clearsky_night
partlycloudy_night
fair_night
fair_night
fair_night
partlycloudy_night
fair_night
cloudy
```